# what is the code for other browser in vtigercrm

Tags: vtiger

this works only  in IE

what is the code,if we want to use mail merge feature in other browser

```
<script>
if (window.ActiveXObject){
    try 
    {
        ovtigerVM = eval("new ActiveXObject('vtigerCRM.ActiveX');");
        if(ovtigerVM)
        {
            var filename = "<?php echo $filename?>";
            if(filename != "")
            {
                if(objMMPage.bDLTempDoc("<?php echo $site_URL?>/test/wordtemplatedownload/<?php echo $filename?>","MMTemplate.doc"))
                {
                    try
                    { 
                        if(objMMPage.Init())
                        {
                            objMMPage.vLTemplateDoc();
                            objMMPage.bBulkHDSrc("<?php echo $site_URL;?>/test/wordtemplatedownload/<?php echo $datafilename ?>");
                            objMMPage.vBulkOpenDoc();
                            objMMPage.UnInit()
                            window.history.back();
                        }       
                    }catch(errorObject)
                    {   
                        document.write("Error while processing mail merge operation");
                    }
                }else
                {
                    document.write("Cannot get template document");
                }
            }
        }
        }
    catch(e) {
        document.write("Requires to download ActiveX Control from vtigerCRM. Please, ensure that you have administration privilage");
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can't, cause of the ActiveX Control.
But on github, there is a mod to accomplish the same task, generating an OpenOffice Document (compatible with Word).
It works only on vtiger 5.4
https://github.com/tsolucio/corebos/commit/21a33c071777a312ca6ce11e4b13889994dc52a4